# Скорее — вводное?

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова

Нужно ли постоянно выделять слово «скорее» запятыми, если оно имеет значение «скорее всего; вернее»? Вот в этом предложении, допустим, как поступить: 
«Этот парень не был его подпевалой, как остальные, а скорее приятелем, хорошим знакомым»?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[СКОРЕЕ](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B5)
**II. *вводное слово.*** Вернее, точнее. *Не верю своим глазам, скорее, не могу поверить. Я не ищу состраданья, скорее, не должен искать.*
**<Скорее всего, *в зн. вводн. словосоч.*** Вероятнее всего. *Скорее всего, задержусь.*

В этом предложении, как мне кажется, по смыслу не хватает глагола «быть»:
*Этот парень **не был** (кем?), а **был** (кем?).*

Тогда предложение (с выделением вводного запятыми) будет иметь такой вид.
**Этот парень не был его подпевалой, как остальные, а был, скорее всего, приятелем, хорошим знакомым.**

Или такой.
**Этот парень не был его подпевалой, как остальные, а был приятелем, скорее, хорошим знакомым.**

P. S. Если слово «скорее» не выделять запятыми, то оно приобретает значение «больше» (при сопоставлении; см. [скорее](https://classes.ru/all-russian/dictionary-russian-academ-term-74229.htm)).
*Этот парень не был его подпевалой, как остальные, а был скорее* (= больше) *приятелем, хорошим знакомым.*

Comment: _"был, скорее всего"_ больше характерно для книжного текста. В разговорной речи это действительно обычно сокращается до _"скорее"_.

Comment: Если посчитать "скорее" вводным, то его можно изъять из предложения. _Этот парень не был его подпевалой, как остальные, а приятелем, хорошим знакомым._ Предложение не имеет смысла. Нужен еще и глагол.

Answer (score 2):

***Этот парень не был его подпевалой, как остальные, а скорее приятелем, хорошим знакомым.***

***Скорее*** не обособляется, если в предложении есть или подразумевается сравнение вида ***скорее...чем*** (из "Справочника по пунктуации" Грамоты.ру).

Здесь: ***скорее приятель, чем подпевала***.